# Need Random product block with Magento Full page cache enable

Tags: magento-enterprise, full-page-cache

I am using the default Magento Full page cache with magento version 1.13.1.0
I have one random product clock listed on home page, but the issue is when I enable full page cache, it stops loading the random product.

Is there any way I can disable the Full page cache for that block only?
I tried with the following, but it seems like it is disabling the full page cache for the entire page. I use this in my block file where the collection is being loaded.

```
 $cache = Mage::app()->getCacheInstance();
 $cache->banUse('full_page');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16852167/disable-full-page-caching-for-specific-block

There's a consise answer there for you mate :)